# How do I undo react-native-upgrade?

Tags: react-native

I have been running a:

```
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.53.3",
```

and I am getting this error and all I do is get one bug to the next between Xcode and the React Native application itself.

I decided to try something like `react-native-git-upgrade 0.54.4` but found all this:

```
deleted:    .lvimrc
deleted:    .tern-port
modified:   android/app/build.gradle
modified:   android/app/src/main/java/com/nfib/engage/MainApplication.java
modified:   android/settings.gradle
modified:   env.js
modified:   index.ios.js
modified:   ios/NFIBEngage.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
modified:   ios/NFIBEngage/AppDelegate.m
modified:   ios/Podfile.lock
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/AppCenter.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSAbstractLog.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSAppCenter.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSAppCenterErrors.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSChannelDelegate.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSChannelGroupProtocol.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSChannelProtocol.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSConstants.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSCustomProperties.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSDevice.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSEnable.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSLog.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSLogWithProperties.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSService.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSServiceAbstract.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSWrapperLogger.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenter/MSWrapperSdk.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/AppCenterAnalytics.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSAbstractLog.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSAnalytics.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSEventLog.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSLogWithProperties.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSService.h
deleted:    ios/Pods/Headers/Public/AppCenter/AppCenterAnalytics/MSServiceAbstract.h
```

I am not prepared to have all these files deleted and so I would like to know, how to do I undo this?

I have not added or committed anything yet to my branch. In fact, it says I am in a `detached HEAD` state.

Comment: git checkout to a different branch or checkout the files manually. so I'm assuming that you are using file versioning.

Comment: `$ git stash` will stash your changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, react-native-git-upgrade is outdated and unreliable. Don't use it for upgrading React Native. Instead, go to https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge and update in small, incremental steps. Once you're on version 0.59, updating will be easier (they replaced the upgrade command with a tool that does a three-way merge based on rn-diff-purge).

Comment: @MarcelKalveram, whoa, that kind of information is crucial to what I am doing. I learned about `react-native-git-upgrade` from a blog from a fellow developer from Belgium.

Comment: @JuniusL., your comment is the solution so please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't committed anything, you can just branch out to a different branch, which will take the changes to that branch with affecting the current branch.

```
# -b creates a new branch
$ git checkout -b unwanted-changes
```

or

```
# will stash your changes and leave the current branch untouched
$ git stash
```